# Are unused constants still compiled or optimized away? If not, how to accomplish?

Tags: c#, .net, static, compilation, constants

I'm programming an Embedded device with netMF. Memory is precious. I am accessing low level MCU registers I want to keep all of these registers in some type of Static class like this for easy access. Not all constants are used in a given program.

**Are the unused constants compiled?**

**If so, is there a better way such that they are not compiled and the program size is smaller, while yielding the same functionality of the static class and getting intellisense is visual studio?**

```
public static class DeviceRegisters
{
    public const uint Tim9 = 0x40014000;
    public const uint Tim8 = 0x40010400;
    public const uint GPIOA_MODER = 0x40020000;
}
```

Then implemented like:

```
public class Thing
{
   public thing(uint timerRegister, uint GPIOx_register)
   {
       //do stuff
       Register thing = new Register(timerRegister);
       //...
   }

}
```

instantiated like:

```
public class Program
{
   public static Thing MyThing;

   public static void Main()
   {
      MyThing = new Thing(DeviceRegisters.Tim9, DeviceRegisters.GPIOA_MODER);
      //rest of program below
   }

}
```

Comment: If `public`, the compiler won't optimize them away, because anything referencing the library might need access to the constant. I don't know if it would `intern` the unused constant, though.

Comment: If memory is a concern, then you shouldn't be using `C#` in first place. E.g. constants in pure `C` aren't something what is in the memory until they are used.

Comment: @willaien are you suggesting to use `internal const` instead of `public const`?

Comment: A decompiler would tell you with 100% accuracy

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if you even want them to be lost in compilation. Since the constants are `public`, they can be used in another assembly referencing it. The compiler won't optimize them away.

<strike>I am pretty sure if they would have been `internal` and unused, the compiler would remove them if in release mode.</strike>

Wrong, seems that even private constants in internal classes are not optimized away in release mode with optimize code option enabled...

And even then, an `uint` only takes 32 bits. Not that much to worry about.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use `internal` instead of `public` on the constants?

Comment: No, you asked whether they would be optimized away. This is my knowledge/experience how they are treated.

Comment: I would like the unused constants to be optimized away. How is that accomplished?

Comment: Mark them `internal`, then build and use a decompiler, like Reflector, to check if they are gone.

Comment: No, they are not optimized away. I have tested all options I know. @GisMofx